# Delaying assignment of IP-address until network adapter device is available

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, init, usb-network-adapter

I'm working on a custom embedded board with three Ethernet interfaces:

- eth0 and eth1 are built-in to the CPU (a TI AM3356)
- eth2 is made with an on-board LAN9512 chip (using the smsc95xx driver), connected through USB

At boot, I want to bring up eth0 and eth1 **without** an IP-address (they are used for industrial Ethernet), and bring up eth2 **with** an IP-address (it is used for standard network communication).

My `/etc/network/interfaces` originally looked like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up
    post-down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up
    post-down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static                                                                                              
    address 10.1.1.10                                                                                           
    netmask 255.255.255.0                                                                                           
    gateway 10.1.1.20
```

This brings up all three network interfaces (and the loopback adapter), but does not assign the specified IP-address to eth2.

Looking in the bootlog I get the message

> ip: can't find device 'eth2'

...and just after that, a message from the smsc95xx driver that it has registered eth2. So I presume it's because eth2 isn't available when the init script tries to assign the IP-address to it (but instead comes up just after).

If I do `ifup eth2` once the board is started, the IP-address is correctly assigned automatically.

I've tried hacking around with some `pre-up` stuff, and the following seems to work just fine:

```
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static                                                                                              
    address 10.1.1.10                                                                                           
    netmask 255.255.255.0                                                                                           
    gateway 10.1.1.20                                                                                           
    pre-up while [ ! -e /sys/class/net/eth2 ]; do sleep 1; done;
```

But it just feels too much like a hack (and will also hang the system if eth2 never shows up).

Is there a "correct" way to get the IP-assignment to wait until the interface is actually there? - or will I have to make a custom script to achieve this?

Note that I'm working on an embedded Linux (kernel 3.18.9-rt5, built with PTXDist), running BusyBox, so I may not have access to all the fancy tools that are available.

Comment: Do you have `udev`?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes, I do. I've only used it for setting up a custom name for a usbpendrive though. Would it be usable for setting the IP also?

Comment: `udev` can fire a script when a device comes up.  Your script can then assign the IP.

Comment: @LawrenceC I did try experimenting a bit with `udev` earlier today - I think I got a working rule set up, but I couldn't get it to run `/sbin/ifup eth2` (either that, or `ifup` just doesn't complete successfully). I'll continue trying stuff when I'm back in the office on Monday though.

Comment: Also since it sounds like you are on Debian you could just add a `sleep 10; ifup eth2` to your `/etc/rc.local` and that might work.

Comment: @LawrenceC I got it working with `udev` - turned out that BusyBox required the correct working directory for its `ifup`, or that the path was set up (which was probably why `ifup` wasn't working from `udev` initially) - see my own answer for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding the following `udev` rule to my `local.rules` file:

```
KERNEL=="eth2", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="smsc95xx", RUN+="/home/bin/enableeth2.sh"
```

The script (`/home/bin/enableeth2.sh`) contains the following (and is set to be executable):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /sbin/
ifup eth2
```

Note the change of directory to `/sbin/` before calling `ifup`, instead of just calling `/sbin/ifup eth2`. This is necessary since the BusyBox `ifup` calls `ip` (located in `/sbin/`) internally, and since the path apparently isn't set up when the `udev` rule runs, `ifup` will give an error when trying to do the actual adapter set up.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to speed up bringing up the interface. This is obtained by adding `allow-hotplug eth2` immediately after `auto eth2` in the stanza of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

According to [Debian's manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_network_interface_with_the_static_ip),

> "auto "   start interface  upon start of the system
>
> "allow-auto "  , ,
>
> "allow-hotplug "  start interface  when the kernel detects a hotplug event from the interface

So, it should be like this:

```
auto eth2
allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet static                                                                                              
address 10.1.1.10                                                                                           
netmask 255.255.255.0                                                                                           
gateway 10.1.1.20
```

**Edit**

Possibly, you need a `udev` rule to `ifup` the interface when udev detects it. You could possibly use a rule like:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{vendor}=="Yoyodyne", ATTRS{model}=="XYZ42", ATTRS{serial}=="123465789", RUN+="/path/to/my/script"
```

by placing it into a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. This is for a USB object, Vendor and Model will have to be fixed to your case, the file `/path/to/my/script` is an **executable** file containing

```
#!/bin/bash
ifup InterfaceName
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't help. With `allow-hotplug eth2` instead of `auto eth2`, `eth2` isn't brought up at all during boot. For reference, `ifup eth2` still works (and assigns the specified ip) after booting, and I also no longer get the "ip: can't find device 'eth2'" message.

Comment: @sonicwave I made a mistake, pls see my redacted answer

Comment: Hmm - I'm pretty sure I already tried that - and that it complained about the `allow-hotplug` being "misplaced" if it was placed after the `auto eth2` line - and then just rejecting the file completely. I'll try it again on Monday when I'm back in the office to make sure. Thanks in any case though!

Comment: @sonicwave You see, the above is what the Debian manual suggests, verbatim. If it does not work, it means there is a problem. We may try with an ad hoc udev rule, but that is once again a hack because it is supposed to work like I described above, no need of further intervention.

Comment: Hmm - I had a quick look at the Busybox code, and it doesn't seem to support `allow-hotplug` - which I guess explains why it doesn't work...

Comment: @sonicwave Mmmmh, I am a bit surprised: I remember busybox having support for hotplug. Googling `busybox allow-hotplug` returns code modifications going back to 2005-2007.

Comment: @sonicwave Pls read my Edit.

Comment: I also found a bit of a patch attempting to add support for `allow-hotplug`, but apparently it never got merged. The current tree doesn't seem to have any sign of it at least. In any case though, I got it working after playing around with `udev` and the script that it calls. Thanks for the input!